# Initialization of canvas with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been recently tying to visualize molecules via the following library:
https://github.com/reymond-group/smilesDrawer. First, I've initialized the drawer as follows:

```
SmilesDrawer.apply({ width: 300, height: 300 });
```

If I create a simple canvas with a data input as follows:

```
<canvas data-smiles=CC=O name=canvasField></canvas>
```

The library works fine, and outputs the desired visualization. However, if I try to set it via jquery (during html rendering), as follows,

```
$('#outputElement').html("<canvas data-smiles=CC=O name=\"canvasField\"></canvas>")
```

Nothing happens. I've checked the html and it seems to be rendered fine, however, the molecule does not show. Am I missing something obvious here? If so, how do I generate canvases with html as shown?

Thanks!

Comment: try this. `$('#outputElement').html("<canvas data-smiles=CC=O name=\'canvasField\'></canvas>");`

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/b1xvnr5o/ Though that would be a good idea to wrap your attribute's value into quotes...

Comment: Tried that, thanks. I'll dig deeper, no idea what would be the problem.

Comment: I fixed it with additional re-initialization of the canvas lib within the request. Thanks for the jsfiddle @Kaiido